# why does jquery .text() always return an empty string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple `$.ajax` call that returns a response that looks like this:

```
<div id='type'>success</div>
<div id="graph"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   //some script that manipulates the graph div
</script>
```

and on my .ajax's success(response) function, I have:

```
$(response).find('#type').text()
```

my problem is that it always returns null if I use `.html()`

and 'an empty string' when i use `.text();`

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: also previously, the div#type was a 'p#type' but still it returns the same result as it is now.

Comment: have you inserted the response into the DOM?

Comment: did you try this $("#type", response).text() not sure though if that will work

Comment: @rob: well i did try that a while ago but its not how im supposed to do it, coz the purpose of retrieving that div's value is so that i could decide if i must insert it to the DOM or not

Comment: @Rob - You don't need do to that, `$(response)` creates a document fragment, which is traversable and much faster to deal with as well :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because it's at the root level of the response, so [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) won't work (because it's not a descendant), you need [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
$(response).filter('#type').text()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your response HTML needs to have a root element so that it can `find()` elements, because `find()` searches descendants of a DOM element. You can achieve this by adding the response to the document's DOM, or to another jQuery DOM element.

You can also do this and it'll work as well:

```
$('<div>' + response + '</div>').find('#type').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

here you can test your code should work fine. you have to have a problem in ajax, try with "alert" to "response" to see what response you get

[test](http://jsfiddle.net/cwyhS/)

Comment: It's worth noting that this test isn't valid, doing a `.find()` on a document fragment created from an AJAX response is *very* different than doing a `document.getElementById()` already *in* the DOM.

Comment: Is very very very different?, In the case of putting the response into a div,
var newres = $ ('<div>' + response + '</ div >');
work well, I understand your explanation, but not so strictly applied in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It cant be something as simple as the single quotes around the id in the type div can it?

(the html, not the js)

Comment: Single or double quotes are interchangeable here, as long as they're matched :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `$.ajax()` request, set `dataType` as `html`